# Scheduling a task in python that repeats itself hourly and another that repeats itself daily

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, scheduling

I am working on a Django web project which stores data from API on hourly as well as a daily basis, am using Django-background-tasks for repetition on an hourly and daily basis. I am not able to figure out how to start the data collection process at a particular time(2:00, 3:00 ......) and than repeat using the regular Django-background-tasks repeat mechanism so as I can later on filter the data from a particularly good time(2:00, 3:00, ..... not 2:15,3:15) to another. So, it would be great if someone points out a specific way to do so. Thanks in advance. I am using windows development environment.

Comment: Use crontab or supervisord to schedule launching your task (and don't set the repeat in the task itself).

Comment: I need to update the daily data at a particular time daily, crontab is rigid for that

Comment: moreover, with windows, we can't use crontab or supervisord.

Comment: Use the equivalent on Windows, django-background-task isn't well suited for specifying a specific time. I don't know what you mean by "crontab is rigid", it's perfectly well suited for running a task at specific times.

Comment: @dirkgroten Ok. Let me take a look at crontab equivalent for windows. Is there any you recommend? Or do you recommend developing in another OS? Like Fedora or Ubuntu?

Comment: Depends where you're going to deploy to when you go into production. I'm sure Windows Server has everything you need, but I'm not familiar with it myself.